# How to create pipe to filter list in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-pipe

I'm facing problem with creating the pipe to filter list from input.

What I would like to have is something like this: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp

Is there anybody who can help me with creating pipe for this?

***Update***, I changed the code with one proposition and it is still not working with my part of code.

Some parts from my code:

*component.html:*

```js
<input id="desc" type="text" placeholder="Alarm name" [(ngModel)]="desc">
  
 <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let name of names" [style.display]="(name | search : desc) ? 'block' : 'none'">
      {{ name }}
    </li>
  </ul>

<div class="alarm-list-item" *ngFor="let alarm of alarmsList" [style.display]="(alarm.Description | search : desc) ? 'block' : 'none'">
     {{alarm.Description }}
  </div>
```

alarmList is an array:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTRfl.png)

*search.pipe.ts* also I had to change the pipe code as "contains" doesn't work and I change type to any:

```js
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'search'
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(list: any, searchText: any): any {
        for(let i=0; i<list.length; i++){
          if(list[i].includes(searchText)){
            return true;
          }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not supposed to do that with a Pipe I believe.

What you want is to perform a pipe operation on your itemssource 'alarmlist' which angular 2 won't allow.

What you could do though is something like this, which I'd not advise since it's ugly code:

https://plnkr.co/edit/3e6cFSBFIf0uYYIgKNZ8?p=preview

My advice would be to make another property: filteredAlarmList which you would edit in the `(change)` event of the `<input>` or the setter of your desc property and then rewrite your ngFor like `*ngFor="let alarm of filteredAlarmList"`

If you need this kind of filtering multiple times you could extract all of this to a seperate components. e.g.: FilterListComponent which will take 2 inputs: searchText and List (in your case AlarmList)

Comment: May you please show me the code with your second proposition? The first one from plnkr.co is not working.

Comment: It is not working exactly as I want - I updated main question.

Comment: It is working :) Thank you! I used this:

import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'search'
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(val: any, searchText: any): any {
    if (val.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()))
      return true;
    return false;
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

something like this could help

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
   name: 'search',
   pure: true
})

export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
   transform(value: any, args:string=''): any {
     console.log(value);
     if(!value) return value;
     else {
        if(value.toLowerCase().indexOf(args.toLowerCase())!= -1) {
           return value;
        }
     }
   }
}
```

In your component

```
@Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
   template: `
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filterValue">
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let name of names">{{name | search:filterValue}}</li>
      </ul>`,
   })

export class AppComponent  { 
   names:Array<string> = ['Agnes','Adele','Binny','Bob'];
   constructor(){

   }
}
```

Comment: I think you swapped <ul> and <li>

Comment: and did you test this code? Is it even possible to put ngFor on <ul>. It's on <li> you want that *ngFor, no?

Comment: you are right..last code was working because ngFor was on li.did not check after editing this but this wont work...